# PHP - wait for an external program to finish

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to **run an external program** which takes **approximately 20 seconds to finish** and to output the result and to return the exit code.

The **problem is that nothing is returned** despite the fact that the program is executed.

How can I **force PHP to wait** for an answer?

Code:

```
echo exec('<command>', $o, $r);
var_dump($o);
var_dump($r);
```

P.S. currently tested in Windows 8.

Comment: How do you know the command executed properly? Are you using the full path to the executable or batch command?

Comment: Also what is the actually command? A custom exe?

Comment: From the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) doc: *Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable . . . . Warning
With safe mode enabled, the command string is escaped with escapeshellcmd(). Thus, echo y | echo x becomes echo y \| echo x.*

Comment: The command is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  imacros://run/?m=1.iim

I know it is executed because I can see Firefox in action. But nothing is returned.